# Why is my code failing Google Accessibility review?

Tags: html, accessibility, forms

Basically, I've got an input & an associated label, both with the same ID. However, Google Accessibility Review is failing it, with the following response:

> Form elements do not have associated labels

To me, because the id is the same and the label is pointing towards the input, then I can't see what's failing here?

Am I missing something blindingly obvious!?

```
<div class="field additional">

<label class="label" for="street_2">
<span>Address</span>
</label>

<div class="control">                                   
<input type="text" name="street[]" value="" title="Street Address 2" id="street_2" class="input-text " autocomplete="off" aria-required="true">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I ran it in Lighthouse and Wave and found no errors.

Comment: Is there a reason you're adding `aria-required` but no `required`?

Answer (score 0):

Many things may explain this :

- you may have another label [linking to the same element](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/6520) conflicting for the same form element,
- elements with the same `id` may appear elsewhere in the same HTML document,
- this message may concern another form element,
- the label itself might not be visible

The fact that your input name is an array (`name="street[]"`) let me think that we have not all the elements to conclude on one of those choices.